# The page should display in a certain div without reload

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have been trying to work on such a script that when i click on the link then in certain div the whole content of the link's page get load i tried the following code but its not working fine and always blink when i click on the link. Kindly let me know if there's any issue and how can i accomplish it wither way:

Live example: http://caremerge.us/ajax/waleed_rai_2/index_FAIZAN.html

```
<script>
    $("#aa").click(function(){
        // load by id on click

            $("#response").delay(10000).load("aa.html");
        });
</script>
    <div id="main-body">        
            <div class="span-19 last" id="response">
    </div>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `#aa` is an `<a>` tag, you can use either `return false` or `event.preventDefault()` to stop the link from going anywhere. `event.preventDefault()` can be placed anywhere in the code block, while `return false` should be placed at the end.

```
$("#aa").click(function(){

    //prevent the page from going anywhere
    event.preventDefault()

    // load by id on click
    $("#response").delay(10000).load("aa.html");

    //return false also does the same thing
    return false;
});
```

Comment: not worked kindly check this link and click on the firest link on the page http://caremerge.us/ajax/waleed_rai_2/index_FAIZAN.html